# Problem with setting the array of pointers in the struct using malloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I want to allocate a memory to an array of pointers in struct, but I receive the following error:

> expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Here's struct code:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char *entity[];
}entity;
```

Here's memory allocation in main function:

```
entity s;
s.entity= malloc(30 * sizeof(char *));
```

IDE underlines s.entity and pops the error I mentioned.

Please, help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: an array is not modifiable.
What you want instead is `char** set`

Comment: The way you wrote this, you should basically use: `entity *s = malloc(sizeof *s + 30 * sizeof *s->set);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your structure does not have a member called `entity`, only `id` and `set`.

You apparently want to allocate the whole structure. This type of struct member called *flexible array member* is useful if you want to allocate the whole structure in one `malloc`.

```
entity *s;
s = malloc(sizeof(*s) + 30 * sizeof(s -> set[0]));
```

This kind of struct members are very useful as you can `realloc` or `free` them in a single call.

Increase the size of the `set` array to `50`

```
entity *tmp = realloc(s, sizeof(*s) + 50 * sizeof(s -> set[0]));
if(tmp) s = tmp;
```

Comment: I am not one of the downvoters, but your first suggestion didn't work because `set` is a flexible array member. I guess you realised, since you edited your answer.

Comment: @Cheatah: What do you see wrong in the first version of the answer? It has `malloc(sizeof(*s) + 30 * sizeof(s -> set[0]));`, which is correct for allocating space for the structure plus 30 elements in the array member.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the very first one was wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Thats how you would allocate the pointers:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char **set;
}entity;

int how_many_pointers = 30;
entity s;
s.set= malloc(how_many_pointers * sizeof(char *));
```

And for each pointer you would have to allocate the space for the corresponding string:

```
int i, string_size;

for(i = 0; i < how_many_pointers; i++)
{
    printf("How many chars should have string number %d ?", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &string_size);
    s.set[i] = malloc((string_size + 1) * sizeof(char)); // string + 1 due to space for '\0'
}
```